# PHP base64_decode() .toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, php, base64, png, todataurl

I have an encoded string created from the Javascript function .toDataUrl(). Every time I try to convert this to binary with PHP base64_decode() it truncates the binary.  I have already tried various items such as the following:

```
//First Attempt    
$encoded = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,',  '', $sig);
    $decodedstring = base64_decode(str_replace(array(' ', '_'), array('+', '/'), $encoded));

    $decodedstring = base64_decode(chunk_split($encoded));

//2nd attempt
    $encoded = str_replace([' ','data:image/png;base64,'],  ['+',''], $sig);
    $decodedstring = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < ceil(strlen($encoded)/256); $i++)
        $decodedstring = $decodedstring . base64_decode(substr($encoded,$i*256,256));

//Other attempt
    $decodedstring = base64_decode( str_replace(['data:image/png;base64,', ' '],  ['','+'], $sig) );
```

None of these produce the correct file.  Also to note, that when I use the standard png base64 online decoders the image looks 100% correct so the issue seems to be happening in the conversion.

Would anyone have additional thoughts.  I have spent a few days trying to research this with no luck.

Comment: Without any sample data we cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sammitch Unfortunately this particular piece of data is something I cannot post as it is a signature.  Additionally we have not been able to replicate it ourselves with a random signature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I made to convert data sent via ajax to php. It has always worked flawlessly for me.

```
function prepare_image($string, $file_name) {
    list($type, $string) = explode(';', $string);
    list(, $string) = explode(',', $string);
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    return $string;
}
```